# Synchronizing configuration between versions of visual studio

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I have coworkers, who work on Visual Studio 2015, I have VS2019 and we share code through TFS.
When I make some changes everything works, but when I push code to server my coworkers cannot build the project because they have errors resulting from the fact that VS allows me new C# functionalities like internal functions, inline declarations etc. Is there a way to configure my VS so that it only lets me do the things it allows them to do? I honestly don't have any point where I can start looking into this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** choose the *language version*, it may solve some of your issues

I believe 20127 will be locked at *C# 7.3*, as shown here [C Sharp (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))

To choose the C# language version for your projects, in the *Solution Explorer*

1. right-click on the project and select Properties
2. Select Build Tab
3. Then Select Advanced button.

This will bring up the *Advanced Build Settings* windows, where you can check the drop-down option for “Language Version” of your choice

Usually, you would set this to latest major or minor, though you your case you would likely choose *C# 7 - 7.3*, which would be compatible with *2017*.

<sub>*Image is for illustrative purpose only*</sub>

[image]

**Very relevant comments by [JonasH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12342238/jonash)**

> The langversion will be saved in the csproj file, so it should be
>   sufficient if it is done once. Also, the language selection dropdown
>   is disabled in the latest version of vs2019, but you may still edit
>   the csproj by hand to add it.

Comment: The langversion will be saved in the csproj file, so it should be sufficient if it is done once. Also, the language selection dropdown is disabled in the latest version of vs2019, but you may still edit the csproj by hand to add it.